# IF statement in Excel with date1 and endtime variables

Tags: if-statement

I have got an excel which has an formula and I am not able to understand how its working.

Here is the formula

=IF(C6=date1,0,IF(D6-endtime<=0,0,IF(D6-endtime>0,(D6-endtime)*1440)))

Can someone spends few minutes to post an explanation, how it works

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at it like this:

```
=IF(C6=date1,
        0,
        IF(D6-endtime<=0,
                0,
                IF(D6-endtime>0,
                          (D6-endtime)*1440
                          #no "else statement" here!
                 )
        )
)
```

So the first thing checked is if the cell C6 equals date1, which I think is a named range.  If they are equal, then the whole equation resolves to the next line, 0

If they are not equal then `D6-endtime` is evaluated, if it is less than or equal to zero, then the equation resolves to zero.

If `D6-endtime` is greater than 0, then the next test is true and the whole equation resolves to `(D6-endtime)*1440`.  There is no else in this last test because equation assumes `D6-endtime` will always be numeric.

Here's how I understand `IF` statements work in excel
`=if(logical test,value if test true,value if test false)`
For logical test, you have to use something that resolves to TRUE or FALSE, or you can specify TRUE or FALSE directly(but then you don't need an IF statement)

value if test true, if the test resolves to TRUE(like 1=1), then the cell will *display* this value, and supply this value to other functions

value if test false, if the test resolves to FALSE(like 1=0), then the cell will *display* this value, and supply this value to other functions.

You can omit value if TRUE/FALSE, and excel will return TRUE or FALSE after evaluation of the statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time to give a simple and lucid explanation. I appreciate your help.